# Two xml with colors

Tags: java, android

I have two xml in folder values with colors:

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow">#23238E</color>
</resources>
```

second_colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow">#DBDB7O</color>
</resources>
```

and I would like get this in TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:text="test" 
    />
```

this working ok, but if i do:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@my_color/yellow"
    android:text="test2" 
    />
```

then I have error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value "@android:my_colors/test")

i know - i can make:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow">#DBDB7O</color>
    <color name="yellow_second">#23238E</color>
</resources>
```

but I would like to have it in separate files.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't use separate files, but you might be able to use [qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) (haven't tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want ? I don't understand :/

You can set color in Java :

```
TextView t = findViewById(R.id.yourText);
t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colors));
```

**EDIT  :**
You have to name your colors differently. Although your colors are in differents files, they are in your unique R file so if name is the same there will be an error.

Try this :

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow1">#23238E</color>
</resources>
```

second_colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow2">#DBDB7O</color>
</resources>
```

and in xml layout :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow1"
    android:text="test2"/>
```

or

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow2"
        android:text="test2"/>
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i get values from file my_colors.xml? I would like use this in xml files

Comment: No you're trying to do this : "@my_color/yellow" and it is impossible i think. "my_color" does not exist

If it was helpful, please +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

No you dont need to create a second xml file, that android only specify/use one xml for using `color` on different values folder. Creating a new xml asides from `color.xml` in the values will not register it as a color

You can go and read it from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

And states:

```
 They contain things such as application source code and resource files. 
 Some are generated for you by default, while others should be created if required
```

The list of xml specified in that websites are the only xml that you can create if it is required by you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define two resources of the same type with the same name with the same qualifiers.

Setting a color in XML using `@color/yellow` is really just saying "find a color resource called 'yellow'". `@color` doesn't define a file name- it is declaring the resource type. Similarly, trying to use `@second_color/yellow` won't tell Android to look for a color named yellow in a file called `second_color.xml`.

When the build tools generate `R`, they will combine all of the `<color>` entries for a given configuration together. If you have a color named "yellow" defined in two separate files that still both reside in your `values/` directory, you will have a problem because there can only be one color resource named "yellow."

You *can* define two yellow colors if they are in `values/` folders with different qualifiers. For example, you could put one yellow in `values-fr/` and a different one in `values-en`, and the first will be used for French speaking countries while the latter will be used for English speaking countries. If you do this, you still just reference the color with `@color/yellow`, but the system takes care of selecting the correct one for you.

If you just want two different shades of yellow for the same application in the same configuration, you should give them different names.